# Final variable not injected with @RequiredArgsConstuctor annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, lombok

I get an error saying that "blank field 'personRepo' is not initialized"

I do not understand why lombok is not injecting my final variable 'personRepo' when I annotated the @Service class with @RequiredArgsConstructor.

@RequiredArgsConstructor says that it injects final fields and variables that are annotated with @NonNull, so I do not understand why.

```
package nr.learning.service;

import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import nr.learning.domain.Person;
import nr.learning.repository.PersonRepo;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {
    
    private final PersonRepo personRepo;

    @Override
    public List<Person> getPersonsByFirstName(String firstname) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> getPersonsByLastName(String lastname) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> getPersonsByFavoriteSoccerTeam(String team) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    
    
}
```

All answers and tips are appreciated!

Comment: This is weird, it should work, I also have service that I just tested like this, and it works well with the RequiredArgsConstructor annotation. Is the IDE throwing a compilation error? If you are using IntellijIdea try Invalidating cache and restart

Comment: I totally agree. It is a compilation error thrown in Eclipse, which is the IDE I use. 
I have had the problems yesterday, and today, and I really don't know why.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by downloading Lombok manually from their site, run the JAR file, and restart Eclipse IDE.